# WordPress: Add form with the Gravity Forms API

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I want to add a form in Gravity Forms after activating a theme.
To do this I tried to use their [API](https://docs.gravityforms.com/creating-forms-with-the-gfapi/).

Unfortunately the docs are not very helpful.

The creation of the form works so far. But the form itself has JavaScript errors in the backend. Every other manually created form works fine.

Do I miss something?

This is my code:

```
// Function to check for existing forms
function form_exists_by_title($form_title) {
  $forms = GFAPI::get_forms();

  foreach ($forms as $form) {
    if ($form['title'] === $form_title) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

// Adding the form
function create_gravity_form_on_theme_activation() {
  if (class_exists('GFAPI')) {

    $form_title = 'Form';

    if (!form_exists_by_title($form_title)) {

      // Erstelle das Formular
      $form = array(
        'title' => $form_title,
        'description' => '',
        'fields' => array(
          array(
            'label' => 'Title',
            'type' => 'text',
            'isRequired' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'Please add a title',
            'size' => 'large',
          ),
          array(
            'label' => 'Content',
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'isRequired' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'Please add content',
            'rows' => 5,
            'maxLength' => 500,
          ),
        )
      );

      $form_id = GFAPI::add_form($form);
    }
  }
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'create_gravity_form_on_theme_activation');
```

These are the erorrs in the console:

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')
    at InitializeForm (form_editor.min.js?ver=2.7.6:1:12590)
    at InitializeEditor (form_editor.min.js?ver=2.7.6:1:1597)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (form_editor.min.js?ver=2.7.6:1:92968)
    at e (load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks&ver=6.2.1:2:30158)
    at t (load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks&ver=6.2.1:2:30460)
I
```

And:

```
caught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at E (scripts-admin.merge-tags.3d49bb55c3c3ab318245.min.js:1:1843)
    at z (scripts-admin.merge-tags.3d49bb55c3c3ab318245.min.js:1:2902)
    at D (scripts-admin.merge-tags.3d49bb55c3c3ab318245.min.js:1:4358)
    at R (scripts-admin.merge-tags.3d49bb55c3c3ab318245.min.js:1:6056)
    at scripts-admin.merge-tags.3d49bb55c3c3ab318245.min.js:1:7606
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Z (scripts-admin.merge-tags.3d49bb55c3c3ab318245.min.js:1:7562)
    at J (scripts-admin.merge-tags.3d49bb55c3c3ab318245.min.js:1:8151)
    at Module.K (scripts-admin.merge-tags.3d49bb55c3c3ab318245.min.js:1:8169)
    at scripts-admin.min.js?ver=caa4ee761009c701fc6e3631d3604424:1:21367
E
```